# phantomjs npm install fails behind proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

Trying to install [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) via [an npm wrapper](https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs) while behind the corporate proxy. I had already set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables so that npm itself would be able to communicate with the registry:

```
export http_proxy=my-company-proxy.com:80
export https_proxy=my-company-proxy.com:80
```

But when it came to the node install.js stage of phantomjs, I got a Protocol not supported error:

```
http.js:1711
    throw new Error('Protocol:' + options.protocol + ' not supported.');
      ^
Error: Protocol:my-company-proxy.com: not supported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the phantomjs npm wrapper code assumes that the proxy info is a complete url, not just a hostname. This resolves the issue:

```
export http_proxy=http://my-company-proxy.com:80
export https_proxy=http://my-company-proxy.com:80
```

npm, git, etc work fine with either format, but for this particular package it needs HTTP_PROXY to have a full URL.

UPDATE: [this related issue](https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs/issues/54) has been resolved and now it can use the same configuration system as npm itself (e.g. if you used npm config command) rather than relying on environment variable.

Comment: This worked after I also removed HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY (unset HTTP_PROXY...)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

1. Open the terminal as an administrator
2. Navigate to your project folder and enter the following commands
3. `sudo npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port -g` then
4. `sudo npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_host:port -g`

Hope this works for you. Good luck.